# PHP While Loop problems server hang for a while then error

Tags: php

Trying to echo out all usernames via twitters public api. I get it to work if i skip the while loop. But i cant seems to get it to work with my loop.

```
 $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=zarazentio1&count=200';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$result = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();



   $results = json_decode($result,true);
   $getfield = $getfield.'&cursor='.$results["next_cursor"];
   echo $nextpage;
 ##  echo $results["users"]["2"]["screen_name"];

   foreach($results["users"] as $follow) {
   echo "</br>";
   echo $follow["screen_name"];



            }while ($results = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest());
```

While i do this it seems just to hang for a while then i get error from my host.
If i remove this part (the last part).

```
while ($results = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest());
```

The script works. I get names from the first page. And i have checked so i get a cursor for next page. But i think i am not understanding the WHILE loop function at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to combine both foreach and while, which is not possible in PHP. If you want to stop iterating after some condition is satisfied, simply use: `if($condition) { break;}`